# Hindi movie where prisoner escapes by collecting matchsticks from prison guard

Tags: identify-this-movie, indian-cinema

I remember seeing this Bollywood Hindi movie on TV around 1990, so it might have released in the mid-80's.

The scene that I remember went something like this:

> A prisoner is in an Indian jail cell, wearing a white striped jail uniform and a
>   dark grey woolen blanket around his upper half. The prisoner walks
>   towards the gate of his cell, where there is a guard. The prisoner asks
>   the guard for a match-stick.
>
> The guard gives him a match-stick. Then the guard asks him something
>   to the effect of "I have been here for the past X years. Every single
>   day you have asked me for a matchstick. What do you do with the
>   matchstick after all?".
>
> The prisoner's reply is epic - *"Kaan khujaata hun."* (Translation: I
>   scratch the inside of my ear.)
>
> But with his back turned, the prisoner breaks off the head of the matchstick, and places it
>   into the fold of his blanket. We now see he has been collecting
>   match-heads for many years and has a huge stash in his blanket.
>
> Somehow (I think by asking the guard for the entire matchbox) the prisoner
>   manages to set all these match-heads in his blanket on fire. Since the
>   woolen blanket is wrapped around him, he is unaffected by the flames.
>
> In the ensuing confusion, the guard enters the cell and soon the
>   prisoner escapes from jail.

Does anyone know which movie I am remembering? Would love to watch this epic scene again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact scene I remember from movie [Toofan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toofan_(1989_film)) starring Amitabh Bacchan in double role.

I remember scene described OP where Saitan Singh escapes the jail/prison. Wikipedia only mentions that he escapes but I do remember the scene. While I was in school I thought what smart move to collect match sticks for years.

This Saitan Singh was played by [Goga Kapoor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goga_Kapoor) and lead actor had no part in this particular scene and policemen are some unknown artists.

It was released in 1989, I do remember in mid 90's it was shown on TV multiple times during the course of 4-5 years.

Comment: Yes it was Toofan - I found the scene.  
https://youtu.be/RSSKa0IJI-s?t=1h33m44s  
Thanks Sourabh!